# Добавление нового json в файл

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Суть такова: нужно добавить новую запись в json файл. Сам код, который уже есть:

```
<html>
<head><title>Get requests</title></HEAD>
<?php
$d4=$_GET['message'];
$d5=$_GET['message2']
$jsonobj='{
    "word1": ".$d4.",
    "word2": ".$d5."
}';
if ($d4 != null){
$fz=fopen("/storage/ssd1/822/2911822/public_html/Test.json",'r+') or die("He удалось открыть файл") ;
fwrite($fz, $jsonobj);
fclose($fz);
}
?>
</html>
```

Что нужно сделать: К примеру, если пришёл ещё один запрос - нужно НЕ перезаписать полностью весь файл, а просто добавить ещё один такой же объект. К примеру:

Если мы отправим "`https://mytest/words?message="Hello!"`",
то образуется файл

```
{
    "word1": ".$d4.",
    "word2": ".$d5."
}
```

Если же мы это повторим, то:

```
{
    "word1": ".$d4.",
    "word2": ".$d5."
}

{
    "word1": ".$d4.",
    "word2": ".$d5."
}
```

Можно ли так сделать? Или нужно SQL использовать в таком случае?

Comment: Только учтите что это не правильный JSON, в том смысле если вы захотите весь файл прочитать и раскодировать в json_decode, у вас будет облом. Для правильного формата вам придётся добавить запятую после первой записи.

Answer (score 4):

Обратите внимание на параметр mode функции fopen()
Вы используете r+, который открывает файл для чтения и записи и помещает **курсор в начало файла**. В Вашем случае, вам подойдет параметр mode "a+"

```
$fz=fopen("/storage/ssd1/822/2911822/public_html/Test.json",'a+')
```

Читайте подробнее в документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php

Также, вы можете попробовать использовать функцию file_put_contents() с флагом FILE_APPEND:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php